# Samsung Galaxy s5 receiving MMS as group messages?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, mms

I have a new Samsung Galaxy s5 which I like however when a single contact decides to message me an MMS (picture/video) my messages start a whole new message thread as a 'Group message'.

I just want the single message thread to continue with the same person when I received a MMS (picture/video) from that contact. Is there a way of making this happen via settings or something?

Much Love!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change application to another is the simplest thing to do. You can find them on google store, one of the best is Textra (in my opinion).